# Keeping a Google Doc (Sheet, etc.) last update time

Tags: google-docs-api, google-workspace

I need to put (among other things) the time of the last update of a Google Document (Doc, Sheet, etc.) in a footer, so that if the document is printed it is possible to distinguish which printed copy is the latest.  This needs to be a script so it is done automatically for users without requiring them to do anything special.  I have a script that does this (at least for Docs), but there are some issues:

- In a Doc there is no onEdit trigger, so I can't determine automatically when the document is updated in order to update the footer.  (I am aware that I would need to prevent my own update from triggering this by ignoring the change I make)
- onOpen can only update the document if the user has edit access to the document.  So if somebody opens the document, edits it, and closes the window, and then another user opens it without edit access, they would see the next to last update time instead of the last update time.
- The current version of my script must be manually bound to each document when it is created.  Is there some way to have it automatically get bound when new documents are created?  Would an add-on work?

Is it possible to use the "[Detect Changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-changes)" API somehow?  I'm not sure this is even going to do what I want, and it seems like it might be complicated to do it this way.

Would a time-driven trigger make sense?  The only problem with this is that time driven triggers don't seem to be able to run more than once per minute (unless in an add-on, which can only run once per *hour*), so that last update time could be off by up to this much.  This probably wouldn't be a big problem, but could occasionally cause some issues.  Also, would running code every minute cause any kind of quota issues?

I tried using [ClockTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder) with a delay of 1000ms, but it wasn't updating.  Then I noticed that the `after` function says it will run the trigger after the specified number of milliseconds *plus or minus 15 minutes*!

Comment: Have you tried using [getLastUpdated()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) ?

Comment: @noogui Yes, that's how I am updating the document to say when it was last updated.  The problem is getting my code to run automatically at the right time.